# How to update deployed css file with IntraWeb

Tags: css, delphi, intraweb

I have specified a css file in the ServerController.pas file, and also placed this file in the "MyIWProject\Win32\Debug\wwwroot" folder.

It works fine in the browser. However, I notice if I update the css file, the css file is not updated in the IntraWeb test server. Searching for files on my HD, I cannot find the location of the IW test server files.

So how do I update the css file on the IW test server?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Oh, simpler than I thought: Just click refresh in browser.

Comment: Depending on the make of browser, if you hold shift while clicking refresh, sometimes some things more are refreshed than with a normal klick on refresh.